# Resolve python package dependencies with pip/tox against monorepo contents

Tags: python, pip, tox

I work on a large Python monorepo containing several interdependent packages. There is a core package named `foo` and various extension packages named with the scheme `foo-*`.

Consider `foo-a` that depends on `foo` and `foo-b`. `foo-a`'s `setup.py` looks like this:

```
### foo-a/setup.py

setup(
    # ...
    pin_version = get_version(),  # gets version of `foo-a`
    install_requires=[
        f"foo=={pin_version}",
        f"foo-b=={pin_version}",
        # ...
    ]
    # ...
)
```

On development branches, `get_version()` will always return the placeholder `0+dev`; for releases, it returns a real version. Thus the various packages stay in sync-- when our users download them from PyPI, they're all the same release, and when our CI installs them into a virtual environment, they're all from the checked-out commit.

Our CI uses `tox` environments to run `pytest`, `pylint`, and `mypy`. Right now, we are stuck double-specifying our internal dependencies, because `tox` is unable to find the correct versions without this. The `foo-a` `tox.ini` contains:

```
### foo-a/tox.ini

# ...
[testenv]
deps =
  -e ../foo
  -e ../foo-b
# ...
```

This is necessary because, without these editable installs, `tox` (via `pip`) will be unable to discover the `0+dev` (i.e. unreleased) versions of `foo` and `foo-b` that it needs.

I am wondering if there's a way around this-- basically what I'm hoping for is some way to configure tox and/or pip to try resolving dependencies against local source trees. Something like this:

```
$ pip --local-path=path/to/foo-packages install ...
```

Then, when `tox` builds a venv installing `foo-a`, it would search for dependencies `foo` and `foo-b` in this local path before hitting the package index. I tried using `--find-links` but I could not get it to work, I think because it only looks for source distributions and doesn't recognize code in an "editable" format (as for `pip install -e ...`) as a candidate.

**Is there any way to get tox/pip to try resolving dependencies against the other packages in our monorepo?**

Answer (score 0):

In previous versions of `tox` 3.x it was possible to build `foo` with `tox` and it installed its ZIP into [distshare](https://tox.wiki/en/3.27.1/example/general.html#access-package-artifacts-between-multiple-tox-runs) directory. Then you could refer in `foo-a` to it like in

```
[testenv]
deps = {distshare}/foo-*.zip
```

This functionality was removed from version 4.x without any straightforward replacement.