# Use Tox with local dependencies

Tags: python, pytest, python-poetry, tox

my project structure is the following

```
py/
├─ projects/
│  ├─ project1/
│  │  ├─ ...
│  │  ├─ pyproject.toml
│  │  ├─ tox.ini
├─ libs/
│  ├─ lib1/
│  │  ├─ ...
│  │  ├─ pyproject.toml
```

**py/projects/project1/pyproject.toml** is something like this

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
...
lib1 = {path = "../../libs/lib1" }
```

**py/projects/project1/tox.ini** is something like this

```
[tox]
isolated_build = True
envlist = py3
minversion = 3.24.4
requires = setuptools >= 60.1.0

[testenv]
whitelist_externals = poetry
commands =
    poetry install -v
    poetry run pytest -vvv
```

Everything is working fine during development and run, but I cannot make the testing work. When running the command `poetry run tox` I got the following error

```
.package recreate: ...
.package installdeps: poetry-core>=1.0.0
py3 recreate: ...
py3 inst: ...
ERROR: invocation failed (exit code 1), logfile:  ....
============================================================================================================== log start ===============================================================================================================
Processing ./.tox/.tmp/package/1/project1-1.0.0.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [16 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
          self.create_dependency(name, constraint, root_dir=package.root_dir)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-nmn7y8qz/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/poetry/core/factory.py", line 244, in create_dependency
          dependency = DirectoryDependency(
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-nmn7y8qz/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/poetry/core/packages/directory_dependency.py", line 41, in __init__
          raise ValueError("Directory {} does not exist".format(self._path))
      ValueError: Directory ../../libs/lib1 does not exist
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 22.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the ...
```

Does anyone know how to force tox to install local dependencies? Thank you very much!

Comment: There is already a similar question - unfortunately without an answer. Not that this helps, but you could at least bookmark or follow the other question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72206509/resolve-python-package-dependencies-with-pip-tox-against-monorepo-contents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tox` tries to create a `sdist` package and install it into the environment. This fails, because the creation of the of `sdist` takes place in a temporary directory and virtual environment, where your relative path dependency does not point to the correct location anymore.

Your `[testenv]` should look like this instead:

```
[testenv]
skip_install = true
whitelist_externals = poetry
commands =
    poetry install -v
    poetry run pytest -vvv
```

Setting `skip_install` to `true` will tell `tox` not to build and install the package. This is unnecessary because you use `poetry install`.